# How to clean up session stored object data after session time out in JSF

Tags: jsf-1.2

I have a scenario in JSF. Where I need to clean up the folders cleared in that session at the end of the session ? how to handle this ?

Can anyone have any better solution ? Appreciate for your help.

~Shyam

Comment: you could use [HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) method to perform opertion on session destroy

Comment: the movement sessionDestroyed called all the session stored objects becoming null.